# Do browsers XSS filters protect against DOM based XSS?

Tags: web-application, web-browser, xss

Many (but not all) browsers come with built in XSS protection that can be activated with a HTTP header:

```
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

As I understand it, it prevents reflected XSS attacks by checking that the document does not contain any fishy looking parts of the query string as it loades. For a modern SPA this is not very useful. The HTML loaded directly from the server is often just static, and all the interesting stuff happends after the page has loaded.

Are there any browsers that have XSS filters that also prevents DOM based XSS? A filter like that would for instance check that something passed to `.innerHTML` is not a malicious reflection from the query string or any other user input, like a textbox.

Is this a thing? Do I have anything to gain from enabling the XSS filter on a SPA?

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe there is anything in any browser exactly like what you are describing. However a [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) could accomplish what you are looking for, in a more-robust way.

For example, if your CSP prevents inline scripting you could effectively prevent any JavaScript passed to `innerHTML` from executing. Note that `script` tags are normally stripped from `innerHTML`, but the CSP would also prevent any inline `on*` attributes from executing. This does of-course mean you won't be able to use inline scripting yourself (at-least without explicitly allowing specific script content), but that's generally considered good practice anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

It may be **possible** by having a static analysis engine inside browsers; by considering its false positives, it becomes **impossible**.

None of the current prevention (XSS filters, CSP) will not be able to protect against the variations of DOM-based XSS such as:

- `$(document.location.hash.slice(1))`: vulnerability in jQuery
- `eval("prompt('code')")`: by considering the meaning of DOM, we need to call this kind of XSS with a different name such as memory-based [JavaScript injection](https://portswigger.net/web-security/dom-based/javascript-injection).

A good reference on DOM-based vulnerability variations: https://portswigger.net/web-security/dom-based

I think it would be necessary to completely **stop!** access to user inputs such as `window.location`, `document.cookie`, `document.referrer`, ... and it's impossible.

Answer (score -1):

**Trusted Types** are coming to get rid of DOM XSS.

There are various implementations of them, including Chrome future features:

```
google-chrome-unstable --enable-blink-features=TrustedDOMTypes --enable-experimental-web-platform-features
```

Or separate polyfill: https://github.com/WICG/trusted-types

Or even tinyfill like this: `TrustedTypes={createPolicy:(n, rules) => rules}`

Detailed description available here: https://gadgets.kotowicz.net/poc/Trusted_Types_TPAC_2018.pdf

Comment: This is interesting, but I am not sure it answers my question. I am interested in the XSS-filters that you control through the X-XSS-Protection header, and not in mitigation of DOM-based XSS in general.

Comment: You can control this "DOM-XSS-filter" through the js policy as well.

Comment: I'm not talking about solving it with JS. I am talking about a specific HTTP header.